# Scala function tries to return Unit instead of Future

Tags: scala, playframework, functional-programming

I am writting a scala function which follows the following workflow:

- take an id as parameter.
- use the id to get a object from mongo database. Here I am using reactive mongo.
- after getting the object make another query to the database to get a list of items and return it.

I have implemented this workflow in the following way:

```
def functionA(id:String):Future[List[Hotel]]={
    var futureHotel = hotelRepository.getHotel(id) // returns Futue[Option[Hotel]]
    val result = for {
      r<-futureHotel
    }yield (hotelRepository.getHotels(r.get.giataid)) // this is supposed to be Future[List[Hotel]]
  }
```

It gives me error message like: `Type mismatch. Found Unit require Future[List[Hotel]]`

As I am new to Scala, I am sure I am missing something. Will be cool if someone can point out. Any clue or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the result to `result`. Assignment in scala is of type `Unit` (doesn't return anything). Remove the assignment, since the last expression becomes the return value.

Also, if the `getHotels` method returns `Future[List[...]]` you'll end up with `Future[Future[List[...]]`. You probably want something like this:

```
def functionA(id:String):Future[List[Hotel]]= {
  for {
    r <- hotelRepository.getHotel(id)
    result <- hotelRepository.getHotels(r.get.giataid)
  } yield result
}
```

This gets translated to a call to `flatMap` that doesn't produce the doubly nested future.

Comment: cool. I wonder, what willhappen if `hotelRepository.getHotel(id)` function fails or it does not find a object for `id`?

Comment: Given its type of `Future[Hotel]`, it can only really throw an exception if it can't produce a `Hotel`, which would in turn produce a failed future and skip the next step. If not finding a hotel is not really an error, then the type of the `getHotel` method should be `Future[Option[Hotel]]`.